# Best practice with azure container instances

Tags: azure-container-instances

Was asked to build a cloud architecture plan in azure with serverless, yet with ability to transition to a kubernetes. So was thinking to use azure container instance since function not really a container deployment model. My limited understanding of aci seems to lacking a lot, e.g. health check, scale, auto heal etc

Question, whats the best practice for aci is there a workaround to support these capabilities, looking at msg website it looks promising but hard to dig out the exact recommended design

> Combine ACI with the ACI Logic Apps connector, Azure queues and Azure Functions to build robust infrastructure that can elastically scale out containers on demand. With Azure Container Instances, you can run complex tasks that are capable of responding to events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Azure container Instance itself, it mainly benefits for its fastest and simplest compare with the VM, AKS, Web App and so on. But you do not have much control on it. And its main aim is to test your image if it can run as you expect.

The Azure Logic or Azure Function, just help you to create and delete the Container Instance in the time you want. Or they can get the state or some message from the Container Instance and no more. So if you want to use the Azure Container Instance and other services such as Azure Logic, you need to know what it can help you.

If you have another questions about this issue, please let me know and I will try my best to help you.

Comment: So it’s true other than test/build, not a good idea to use aci in production as a container host environment, due to the lack of scaling and resilience support.

Comment: @TommyWang Yes, it's not appropriate for production, just for test. For production, I will recommend the AKS or the VM directly more.